# pear php translit gives error

Tags: php, pear, transliteration

hi i'm working on a multilanguage project and. and i'm having some problemsi with iconv's //TRANSLIT. so i found [this](http://pecl.php.net/package/translit) package. i succesfuly installed that package to my linux box but when i tried to install it on windows pear gives this error:
**ERROR: The DSP translit.dsp does not exist.** i couldn't find  i compiled dll eigther. 
can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please look at mb_convert_encoding function. your translit package is only linux.